# Django Sitemap Error: 'datetime.time' object has no attribute 'timetuple'

Tags: python, django, xml-sitemap

I am using Django's built-in sitemap feature to dynamically create sitemap. But I keep getting this error, and I don't know why.

Traceback:

> File "/home/fancychamps/Django Projects/EduwizardTutorials/EWTEnv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
> response = get_response(request)
> File "/home/fancychamps/Django Projects/EduwizardTutorials/EWTEnv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
> response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
> File "/home/fancychamps/Django Projects/EduwizardTutorials/EWTEnv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
> response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
> File "/home/fancychamps/Django Projects/EduwizardTutorials/EWTEnv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/sitemaps/views.py", line 16, in inner
> response = func(request, *args, **kwargs)
> File "/home/fancychamps/Django Projects/EduwizardTutorials/EWTEnv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/sitemaps/views.py", line 77, in sitemap
> else site_lastmod.timetuple()
> AttributeError: 'datetime.time' object has no attribute 'timetuple'

My Code:

```
class NoteClassSitemap(sitemaps.Sitemap):
    priority = 0.5
    changefreq = 'monthly'

    def items(self):
        return Classes.objects.all().order_by('-date')

    def lastmod(self, obj):
        return obj.date
```

Comment: Is the `date`  attribute of your model a DateField? Is it possible to make it a DateTimeField?

Comment: Can you please share your views.py

Comment: sure I am adding it.

Comment: thanks @akhilsp I got the error in models it is TimeField not DateTimeField

Comment: Glad to know it worked!